# MVC model is losing data retrieved from not displayed controls in the view

Tags: jquery, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, bpopup

I have to show a lot of data in a form. A lot is like a hundred attributes, each with a calification rank users has to use to put their level of knowledge. Low, high, good, and so on.

I implemented the first one like this

```
    <h3>Conocimiento Informatico</h3>

    <h5>Category Title</h5>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IKOfficeCommunication, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IKOfficeCommunication.LevelSkillId, new SelectList(Model.InformaticSkillLevels, "SkillLevelID", "Name"), "Select Level")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IKOfficeCommunication)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.IKOfficeCommunication.InformaticKnowledgeId)
        </div>
    </div>
```

And it worked. then I say, let´s do a little tweak and put that into a div I can hide and show using bPopup jquery plugin. My objective, not to show all hundreth attributes at once but allow a clenaer view of the form.

```
    //Here is the category title that I use as the trigger for the model popup
    <h5><a href="#" onclick="$('#divIKC0').bPopup(); return false;"> @Model.InformaticKnowledgeCategories[i].Name</a></h5>

    //here is the hidden div, shown with bPopup plugin
    <div id="divIKC0" style="background-color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; width: 60%;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div>
                    <h4>Category Title</h4>
                    <a href="#" onclick="$('#divIKC0').bPopup().close(); return false;" style="float: right; bottom: 30px; position: relative;">Close</a>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IKOfficeCommunication, new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IKOfficeCommunication.LevelSkillId, new SelectList(Model.InformaticSkillLevels, "LanguageSkillLevelID", "Name"), "Nivel")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IKOfficeCommunication)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IKOfficeCommunication.InformaticKnowledgeId)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But now, when the model is sent back to the post action in the controller, the property is null.

I have this script too at the end of the view for hiding the div when the page loads. Then bPopup plugin shows it or hides it.

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/chosen-ajax.js")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#divIKC0").hide();
</script>
}
```

Why the model does not get the property loaded when the div is hidden? How can I workaround this?

Comment: In my opinion, MVC model is not great, and old. I will use FRP for instance bacon.js.

Comment: You are saying if you explicitly show the div, the value is POSTed back? Do you have a form tag in your page?

Comment: Yeas, exactly that. I ave a form, and when the div is display:none, it´s controls don´t post its values, but when is displayed, it works. I´m using Razor by the way, which is default tool for Views in VS. sadly I can not get rid of it in this proyect :(

Comment: And The content toggled is within the form, of course.

Comment: When the div is hidden, is the html removed from the page?